# Mailgun Error 'The parameters passed to the API were invalid

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mailgun

I am using mailgun to help me with sending mails on laravel.

Here mail code:

```
$data = array('name' => ucfirst($customer_name),'email' => $email, 'ticket_id' => $ticket_id);
$mail_data = array('name' => ucfirst($customer_name),'email' => $email, 'mobile' =>  $contact, 'address' => $address, 'delivery_type' => ucfirst(Input::get('delivery_type')), 'pickup_type' => ucfirst(Input::get('pickup_type')), 'pickup_date' => $pickup_date, 'pickup_time' => $pickup_time, 'brand' => $brand_name, 'ticket_id' => $ticket_id, 'city' => $region_name);

Mailgun::send('emails.ticket', $mail_data , function($message) use($data)
{
  $message->to($data['email'], $data['name'])
          ->bcc(array('myemail@mydomain.com, aotheremail@mydomain.com, onemore@mydomain.com, lastone@mydomain.com'))
          ->subject('Service Request! - '.$data['ticket_id']);
            });
```

I checked the logs figured out:

```
[2016-12-29 05:58:58] production.ERROR: exception 'Mailgun\Connection\Exceptions\MissingRequiredParameters' with message 'The parameters passed to the API were invalid. Check your inputs! Sandbox subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own domain or add the address to authorized recipients in Account Settings.' in /var/www/html/mysite/vendor/mailgun/mailgun-php/src/Mailgun/Connection/RestClient.php:169
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/mysite/vendor/mailgun/mailgun-php/src/Mailgun/Connection/RestClient.php(88): Mailgun\Connection\RestClient->responseHandler(Object(GuzzleHttp\Message\Response))
#1 /var/www/html/mysite/vendor/mailgun/mailgun-php/src/Mailgun/Mailgun.php(106): Mailgun\Connection\RestClient->post('sandbox798d350d...', Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/html/mysite/vendor/mailgun/mailgun-php/src/Mailgun/Mailgun.php(53): Mailgun\Mailgun->post('sandbox798d350d...', Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/html/mysite/vendor/bogardo/mailgun/src/Bogardo/Mailgun/Mailgun.php(104): Mailgun\Mailgun->sendMessage('sandbox798d350d...', Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/html/mysite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(222): Bogardo\Mailgun\Mailgun->send('emails.ticket', Array, Object(Closure))
#5 /var/www/html/mysite/app/Http/Controllers/AppController.php(384): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('send', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/mysite/app/Http/Controllers/AppController.php(384): Bogardo\Mailgun\Facades\Mailgun::send('emails.ticket', Array, Object(Closure))
#7 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\AppController->pickup_request()
#8 /var/www/html/mysite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(256): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#9 /var/www/html/mysite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(164): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('pickup_request', Array)
```

I am not able to figure where the problem is? is it the syntax error? or what could be wrong?

It used to work properly now it has stopped.

Thanks!

Comment: What's `Mailgun`? Is that laravel's `Mail`?

Comment: @LionelChan: http://www.mailgun.com/

Comment: No I know what's mailgun. It's a mail service. What I meant is how come you are sending email via `Mailgun::send` but not `Mail::send`?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: You are using https://github.com/Bogardo/Mailgun to send emails via https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php library?

Comment: @LionelChan: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The error tells everything :)

> The parameters passed to the API were invalid. Check your inputs! Sandbox subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own domain or add the address to authorized recipients in Account Settings.

In Mailgun, sandbox subdomains are only for testing. If you need to really sending out emails you will need to add your domain name into your mailgun acc, or add authorized recipients into your mailgun account settings.

So in this case, you will need to either add `mydomain.com` into your mailgun whitelisted domains, or add `myemail@mydomain.com`, `aotheremail@mydomain.com`, `onemore@mydomain.com`, `lastone@mydomain.com` into whitelisted emails.

Relevant docs: https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/217531258-Authorized-Recipients

Related Q&A: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/sending-emails-with-mailgun